# Utilizar Pascal en GNU Emacs 25 (GUI) -- Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pascal, emacs

Tengo instalado GNU Emacs en Ubuntu 17.10, y me gustaría saber si puedo utlizarlo para trabajar con Pascal, ya que el famoso "fondo azul" me resulta muy incomodo para trabajar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que te incomoda son los colores, puedes cambiar de tema. [Aquí un tutorial](https://ondahostil.wordpress.com/2016/10/26/lo-que-he-aprendido-cambiar-el-tema-de-emacs/) de los varios que hay.

En cuanto al lenguaje de programación, Emacs soporta pascal de forma nativa. Al editar un archivo con extensión `.pas`, el modo de edición Pascal se selecciona automáticamente.